# Datepicker directive causes infdig (infinite digest loop) error

Tags: angularjs, jquery-ui, datepicker

This AngularJS 1.2.21 directive is used as an universal solution to be used in browsers supporting type="date" and not supporting it.

```
directive('datePicker', function(){

        var el = document.createElement('input');
        el.setAttribute('type','date');
        var typeDateSupport = (el.type === 'date');        
        return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
                if (typeDateSupport) {
                    elm.attr('type', 'date');
                    elm.attr('placeholder', null);
                    /* Type date takes care of the right format. The display value is localized, the real value is always YYYY-MM-DD,
                        so that we do not need to add any parsers and formatters */
                } else {
                    elm.attr('type', 'text');
                    elm.attr('readonly', 'readonly');
                    elm.datepicker({
                           dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', // TODO: internationalize this
                       onSelect: function(date) {
                          scope.$apply(function() {
                             ctrl.$setViewValue(date);
                          });
                       }
                    });
                    if (attrs.hasOwnProperty('max')) {
                        elm.datepicker('option', 'maxDate', $.datepicker.parseDate('yy-mm-dd', attrs.max));
                    }
                    ctrl.$formatters.unshift(function(value) {
                        if (angular.isUndefined(value)) {
                            return undefined;
                        }
                        return moment.utc(value).tz(Config.timeZone).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
                    });
                    ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function(value) {
                        if (angular.isUndefined(value)) {
                            return undefined;
                        }
                        var tmp = moment.tz(value, Config.timeZone);
                        ctrl.$setValidity('date', tmp.isValid());
                        return tmp.isValid()? tmp : undefined;
                        return value;
                    });

                }

            }
        };
    })
```

The code causes this error: **`Error: [$rootScope:infdig]`** in IE 11 (not supporting `type="date"`). I have actually no idea, why....
Could somebody help?

Comment: What happens if you remove the `scope.$apply` call in the else clause?

Comment: I figured out, the reason is the parser. Deleting it removes the issue. But we need it.

Comment: Cool. Make sure you answer your own question so that others can benefit :)

Comment: No, it's not solved. We NEED the parser, I cannot just delete it. I would know WHY it causes the problem.

Comment: Oh sorry, I misunderstood

Comment: It's amazing, but you were right. Removing the `scope.$apply` solved it. Looks like the `apply` caused the parser to be called in an infinite loop. Can you post your comment as answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Awesome! I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the call to `scope.$apply`. It's usually related to such errors.